# make and export path

Tags: bash, path, makefile, export

I am trying to install opengazer ( see http://sourceforge.net/projects/opengazer/ )
once extracted, I go into the folder and use the command make as specified in the readme.txt file.
However, it seems the c++ code is compilated, and I get a nice path error: 
    utils.h:7:30: fatal error: vnl/algo/vnl_svd.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.

The desired library (comprising  "vnl/algo/vnl_svd.h" ) is located on my desktop: /home/me/Desktop/vxl-1.14.0/core/

I tried to export the path: export PATH=$PATH:/home/me/Desktop/vxl-1.14.0/core/

Then I ran the make command again but it doesn't work, compilator still fails to reach vnl/algo/vnl_svd.h.

What can I do (except retyping every preprocessor inclusion in each header files) ?

Comment: Probably not the issue, but you should quote `$PATh`, i.e. `export PATH="$PATH:/home/me/Desktop/vxl-1.14.0/core/"`

Comment: Yep if only it could solve the problem :P

Comment: `PATH` is useless for this.  `PATH` tells the shell where to look for _commands to run_.  It is of no use whatever in locating _include files_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PATH` will do nothing for you.  You have to examine the makefile and find the location where the directory is specified, and modify it to point to your directory.

In this Makefile the very first line is `VXLDIR = /opt`.  You should edit the makefile and change that to point to your installation of vxl.

Just to point out, this information is *right in the README file*!!

> Edit the VXLDIR variable in the Makefile to point to your vxl include headers

Comment: Yes thank you! I first edited the VXLDIR correctly as specified in the README. However I did not pay attention to the INCLUDES variable using "foreach prefix, ,,, (foreach suffix ,, )), there was the problem :)
Now we are at it, compiler now need the vxl_config.h file. However there are 4 different files located in subdirectories bearing the same name! How can I know which is the right one?
(
; /vxl-1.14.0/vcl/config.win32/vc60/vxl_config.h
; /vxl-1.14.0/vcl/config.win32/vxl_config.h
; /vxl-1.14.0/vcl/config.win32/vc70/vxl_config.h
; /vxl-1.14.0/vcl/config.stlport.win32-vc60/vxl_config.h )